# Firestore: Checking NotNull in a transaction and impede from calling the OnSuccessful callback

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

In the function `apply` of my Firestore transaction, I've written `DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(xyz);` so that I get a reference to the document snapshot. I want to read one of it fields, but before I should check this field is contained (`if(snapshot.contains("the field"))`) and if it's not null (`if(snapshot.getDouble("the field")) != null`). **Otherwise, I show an error message.**

Also, I have written a validation message in the callback `OnSuccess`, which is triggered if the transaction could run (*i.e.:* if `apply` returned).

**So both the error message and the validation message will be shown.**

Below is an example:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Void apply(@NonNull Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
                                        DocumentSnapshot snapshot = transaction.get(object_to_update);
                                        if(snapshot.contains("amount") && snapshot.getDouble("amount") != null) {
                                            double new_amount = snapshot.getDouble("amount") + seek_bar_value;
                                            transaction.update(object_to_update, "amount", new_amount);

                                        } else {

                                            Toast.makeText(context, "Error: Unable to find a required field to process the transaction correctly.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                        return null;
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Error: Unable to update the data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "Congratulations, the data has been updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

So the problem is that the message "Error: Unable to find a required field to process the transaction correctly." and {the message "Congratulations, the data has been updated." or "Error: Unable to update the data."} will be both shown.

**How could I fix this problem?** Perhaps I could use a boolean in the callback `OnSuccess` to know if the `apply`'s checks Contains and NotNull didn't show the error message, so that `OnSuccess` can show the validaton message, for example. But is there another way to solve the problem?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is here.  I suggest editing the question to show the code you've written, since what you're describing now is difficult to visualize.

Comment: @DougStevenson , I'm sorry, it was late. I completely rewrote the PO, which now shows the sources, explanations, among others. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps I could use a boolean in the callback OnSuccess to know if the
>   apply's checks Contains and NotNull didn't show the error message, so
>   that OnSuccess can show the validaton message, for example. But is
>   there another way to solve the problem?

You should read the documentation on [passing information out of transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#passing_information_out_of_transactions).  It gives you a pattern to use to determine if your transaction succeeded or failed.  You should throw an exception out of your `apply` function in order to get the transaction to fail correctly.  Right now, you are unconditionally returning null, which always means the transaction succeeded.

Comment: Oh sorry, I read this article but thought it concerned only transaction in which a value is returned. But indeed, a `Transaction.Function<Void>` can be treated like that. Sorry. However I have a last question Doug: where could I `try/catch` the `FirebaseFirestoreException` thrown by `apply`? I thought I'd be able to put `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().runTransaction` in this `try` and `catch` the exception, but no.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  Please post a new question and explain what's not working the way you expect.